# NetSuite PDF Templates (Mail Merge)

Tags: pdf, netsuite

I'm new to the forum and am seeking some assistance with a specific NetSuite problem.

I am attempting to create and upload a few PDF documents for mail merge purposes within NetSuite (I believe this is a completely different function to NetSuite's powerful Advanced PDF Templates), but am having extreme difficulty getting the field tags to populate.

I've tried to use the CRMDSK field tags referenced by NetSuite in the help articles, as well as the freemarker tags.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to get these fields to populate and what field tag language to use?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Also, how do you properly enter a field tag into a PDF document using Acrobat? I am using Adobe Acrobat DC 2016.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a static pdf or a pdf with form fields that a user will fill in?